# how to do async await on a forEach function

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, async-await

I'm a beginner in async await and promises. I read few articles and watch few tutorial videos but I am still not able to understand it completely.
So I have a code that I'm working on right now

```
}).then(function() {
  var responseArray = []
  [url1,url2,url3,url4].forEach((url)=>{
      makeRequest(url)
  }).then((response)=>{
      responseArray.push(response)
  })
  return responseArray
})
```

So as expected the `responseArray` is returned empty. I need to make it wait until all the responses from each makerequest(url) is pushed to the responseArray.
This is my attempt

```
}).then(function() {
      var responseArray = []
      [url1,url2,url3,url4].forEach((url)=>{
          async makeRequest(url)
      }).then((response)=>{
          await responseArray.push(response)
      })
      return responseArray
    })
```

Can anyone help me fix this one?

Comment: Where the rest of the code? You need the outer promise too to refactor this correctly

Comment: Async await + Array.prototype.map(): `.then(async () => ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'].map(async url => await makeRequest(url)));`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to map the requests to an array of promises then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
.then(async () => {
  const responseArray = await Promise.all(
    [url1, url2, url3, url4].map(makeRequest)
  );
})
```

This will execute all the requests in parallel (which is generally what you want unless you want to limit the bandwidth etc).

If you want to execute them sequentially, there's a [huge discussion on the best approach](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1122).

Comment: yes, `makeRequest` should return a promise.

Comment: super it worked!

Answer (score 8):

You cannot wait for all the promises to be resolved if you use `forEach`. Use `for .. of` instead:

```
}).then(async function() {
    var arr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];
    var responseArray = []; 
    for (url of arr) {
        cont response = await makeRequest(url);
        responseArray.push(response);
    }
    return responseArray;
});
```

Or, for a better performance, you can use Promise.all to launch all your requests in parallel:

```
}).then(async function() {
    var arr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];
    var responseArray = await Promise.all(arr.map(function(url) {
        return makeRequest(url);
    }));
    return responseArray;
});
```